# WinRT Metro ListView content row/size limit

Tags: listview, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Regarding WinRT `ListView`...

1. Is there a row or size limit on the control. i.e, will it render
   only up to a certain number of rows?

**OR**

1. Will the `ListView` keep filling with items until an
   `OutOfMemoryException` is reached, or all data is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can specify height / width properties to ensure that it doesn't grow beyond those.

I prefer to use grid layout and force listview to have that as max size.

The listview support data virtualisation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx

This means that any data that is not visible on screen isn't rendered and will only be rendered if it comes into view. this is the default option.

Comment: So, does that mean that the number of items I can load into the ListView is unlimited? It does some clever recycling of resources, depending on whats visible or not.

Comment: yes have a look at DataFetchSize property and here's more.. "ListView supports data virtualization to improve performance with large data sets. Random access virtualization is supported when the data source implements the IObservableVector or INotifyCollectionChanged interface"

Comment: know of a sample for "Random access virtualization" ?